# Azure VMs and Min requirements

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure

Whats the story with VMs running on Azure, they offer a number of teirs of resources, however it appears that they offer resources below what is recommended as the minimum for the OS i.e.

Standard Tier pricing AO - VM - 1 Core 0.75 GB of Ram ?

Windows Server 2012 - Req min Ram - 2GB https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dn383626.aspx

Am I missing something here? How well will an A0 tier server run Windows?

Comment: First, you're looking at the wrong page. Did you not see this? "Are you looking for system requirements for Windows Server 2012 R2? If so, go to [System Requirements and Installation Information for Windows Server 2012 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dn303418) in the Windows Server TechNet Library."

Comment: Second, you miss that sometimes a super small vm is enough. Run only a DNS server? 0.75gb is actually enough to have some reserves during patching ;)

Comment: You can choose any one of a number of VM images or you can upload and use your own. The instances aren't tied to a specific OS, version or edition, so the instances aren't "below what is recommended for the OS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a D1 v2 Machine, and works nicely for the load on it, the server has a varnish proxy in front so doesn't get all hits and never hits over 10% CPU at this stage (usually < 2% avg) - unless I'm on the device running tasks (Builds, Backups etc etc) - Is running IIS, and SQL Express and running nicely with a few websites - websites are custom built code using alot of caching and not very labor intensive applications so is a great starting size - Ive added a SSD as a data disk which I'm sure is also very help.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your original StackOverflow post: You can run a Windows Server VM in *any* available VM size, including the shared-core A0. It might not run as well as a larger VM size, but it will still run. I think you're getting caught up in published recommended specs, which are guidelines but not requirements.

Only you can determine "how well" an A0 will run Windows Server, based on the software and load you put on it. You'll need to test. Just start a new A0 Windows Server VM; should only take a few minutes.

Comment: Ok thank you, Ill be running a web server and it looks like the most effective way to run a DB will be to install that locally, (Per DB install runs the price up a fair bit) - will have to have a play with the options available to determine what will suit.